# Wrong print value $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code:

```
    var marcas = {
        nome: '',
        fipeId: ''    
    };

    var marcasVet = [];
    var select;


$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://fipeapi.wipsites.com.br/carros/marcas',

    success: function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            marcas.nome = data[i].name;
            marcas.fipeId = data[i].id;            


            marcasVet[i] = marcas;

            select += '<p> Marca: ' + marcasVet[i].nome + ' Marca id (Fipe): ' + marcasVet[i].fipeId + '</p>';

        }

        $('#info').html(select);
    }

});
```

The data  are stored in the `marcasVet[]` array and are shown into a div with   `id="info"`

By changing the code from `$('#info').html(select);` to `$('#info').html(marcasVet[10].fipeId);` or `any other index` it prints only the value 120 and it is not what is expected as shown in the code `$('#info').html(select);`.

Anyone knows where is my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your select you added your own words and

tags to get what you see. However when you do a `marcasVet[10].fipeId` that only returns you the `fipeId` and not what you have formatted for the select variable that why u only see 120 instead of when you do a `$('#info').html(select);`

---

What you can do is probably

```
select = '<p> Marca: ' + marcasVet[10].nome + ' Marca id (Fipe): ' + marcasVet[10].fipeId + '</p>';

$('#info').html(select);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
marcasVet[i] = marcas;

select += '<p> Marca: ' + marcasVet[i].nome + ' Marca id (Fipe): ' + 
marcasVet[i].fipeId + '</p>';
```

using this :

```
marcasVet.push({
 nome:marcas.nome,
 fipeId:marcas.fipeId
});

select += '<p> Marca: ' + marcas.nome + ' Marca id (Fipe): ' + 
marcas.fipeId + '</p>';
```

and also you can using $.each instead of for loop if you can using jquery:

```
$.each(data, function( index, item) {
  marcasVet.push({
  nome: item.nome,
  fipeId: item.fipeId
});

select += '<p> Marca: ' + item.nome + ' Marca id (Fipe): ' + 
item.fipeId + '</p>';

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following in the ajax part of your code

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://fipeapi.wipsites.com.br/carros/marcas'
  }).done(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

          marcas = {
            nome: data[i].name,
            fipeId: data[i].id
          };


          marcasVet[i] = marcas;

          select += '<p> Marca: ' + marcasVet[i].nome + ' Marca id (Fipe): ' + marcasVet[i].fipeId + '</p>';

        }


        $('#info').html(select);
 });
```